# showexpl LTXexample and references inside enumerate

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, verbatim

I've used the wonderful `LTXexample` environment defined by `showexpl` to illustrate some LaTeX basics. However, the following code confuses it: the reference remains **??** no matter how many times I recompile...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[frame=none]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item No need to manually number items here!
  \item\label{second} Number two added automatically
  \item Third item
  \end{enumerate}
  And here is a reference to item number \ref{second}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

I've managed references inside `LTXexample` in equation environments, so this is something specific to enumerate... Any ideas how to fix it? (I can't even cheat and just put "2" because the code is shown side-by-side with it...)

**UPDATE:** I emailed the author of `showexpl` but I've had no reply. Does anyone feel like delving into the code to see if it's obvious how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is deliberate. showexpl sets quite a lot commands to \@gobble in \SX@@preset. The SX@1-label is from LTXexample itself, not from the \label{second}. You can reactivate \label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}
\let\orilabel\label
\begin{LTXexample}[frame=none,preset=\let\label\orilabel]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item No need to manually number items here!
  \item\label{second} Number two added automatically
  \item Third item
  \end{enumerate}
  And here is a reference to item number \ref{second}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Can you also explain _why_ showexpl does this to the `\label`? I just can't see what this feature is good for.

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps it breaks in some cases. Or Rolf did so that you can use `\label{second}` in another example without conflict. Or perhaps he copied simply the list of commands from latex.ltx: `\label` is deactivated in other commands too.  Btw: The list contains a tipo `\let\tableofcontens\relax`.

Comment: Why does this make labels break for enumerate, but not for equation? That seems weird...

Comment: It breaks for the original equation too. This changes if you load amsmath: amsmath has to process quite often the content of an equation twice. So it stores the original \label definition and restores it in the equation and so isn't affected if \label is changed somewhere in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug somewhere in `showxmpl` to me. If you look in the `.aux` file, rather than the expected label you see

```
\newlabel{SX@1}{{}{1}}
```

So if you hack the `.aux` to read

```
    \newlabel{second}{{2}{1}}
```

then things will work but of course you'll have to re-do this every LaTeX run.