# What is the best approach to insert a LaTeX example source with preamble?

Tags: tcolorbox, verbatim, examples, showexpl

### Introduction

I was preparing some examples of how to use LaTeX and then I found out the package `showexpl` ([showexpl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)) which worked much better than others such as `verbatim`, `moreverb` and `fancyvrb-ex`. Mainly because it not only shows source code and results but also has access to any `style` defined by the `listings` package through `lstdefinestyle`.

One day, I had to insert (external) files with preamble (`\documentclass{}` and `\begin{document}`) as examples, and `showexpl` also worked fine.

Later, I learned about `tcolorbox` ([tcolorbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d3FOm.png)) and its large set of possibilities and flexibilities.
The following images are from the MWE below and ilustrates both styles.

[image]

I could then create new styles to LaTeX examples until the point I had to use files with preamble.
In this case, there a solution inserting the generated PDF, which by the way is indeed much better than I had with `pdfpages`. But it needs some clipping as follows.

[image]

#### Main issue

An alternative I built was to insert `\LTXinputExample` inside a `tcolorbox`, but I don't understand how could I format the box as I previously did. I mean, `bicolor` with the division dashed line (`overlay`, since `bicolor` seems to remove the default `separation line`).

[image]

#### Questions

1. Is there any method to get the style from section (3) (MWE) of `tcolorbox` with an example that contains preamble without loading the PDF as a comment?
2. If 1 is false. Is there any method the make the clipping of PDF automatically find the boundaries of the text? (some math with `\textwidth` and others measures in `graphics options={viewport=5cm 24.5cm 8cm 25.5cm,clip}`?)
3. If 2 is false. Is there any method to format the box with two colors and a corrected place division line.

OBS: I'm aware I don't need to present every single result of every single example source. What bothers me is the impossibility of not being able to get style (3) with `tcolorbox` when there is a preamble in the example.

#### Sources

1. [Article example inside beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222475/article-example-inside-beamer-frame/222498#222498)
2. [How to use showexpl with an external class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/how-to-use-showexpl-with-an-external-class)
3. [`showexpl` doesn't work with accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192865/showexpl-doesnt-work-with-accents)
4. [showexpl LTXexample and references inside enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6337/showexpl-ltxexample-and-references-inside-enumerate)

---

#### External file and MWE

File: `input_example`

```
This is {\LaTeX}.
```

File: `input_example_preamble`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is {\LaTeX}.
\end{document}
```

MWE with `listing` and `tcolorbox` styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usepackage[skins,listings,breakable,raster]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinestyle{estiloExemVerm}{
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=1em,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  frame=single,
  framesep=\fboxsep,
  framerule=\fboxrule,
  xleftmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
  xrightmargin=\dimexpr\fboxsep+\fboxrule\relax,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  keepspaces=true,
  breakindent=0pt,
  tabsize=2,
  columns=flexible,
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  aboveskip=0.1em,
  belowskip=1.0em,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\hbox{},
  pos=r,
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  preset=\small\setlength{\parindent}{10pt},
  extendedchars=true,
  keywordstyle=\color{red},
  rulecolor=\color{red},
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}
}

\newtcbinputlisting[]{\mytcbRed}[2][]{%
  bicolor,
  lower separated=true,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
  breakable,
  listing and text,
  colframe=red!70!black, colback=red!10!white, coltitle=red!10!white,
  sidebyside,
  overlay={
    \draw[dashed, red!80!black,thick] (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);
  },
  listing options={style=estiloExemVerm},
  listing file={#2}, #1
}

\newtcbinputlisting[]{\mytcbInputListing}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  colback=red!10!white, colframe=red!70!black, fonttitle=\large\sffamily\bfseries,
  sidebyside, bicolor, colbacklower=white,
  listing and comment,
  overlay={
    \draw[dashed, red!80!black,thick] (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);
  },
  listing options={style=estiloExemVerm},
  listing file={#2},
  pdf comment={#2.pdf},
%  comment style={raster columns=1, colframe=red!85!black, boxrule=2pt, %drop fuzzy shadow,  %shadow={2mm}{-2mm}{0mm}{black!50!white},
%    graphics options={viewport=5cm 24.5cm 8cm 25.5cm,clip}},
  #1,
}

\begin{document}
  
\section{LTXinputExample -- preamble}

\LTXinputExample[style=estiloExemVerm]{input_example_preamble}

\section{LTXinputExample -- without preamble}

\LTXinputExample[style=estiloExemVerm]{input_example}

\section{tcbinputlisting -- without preamble}

\mytcbRed{input_example}

\section{tcbinputlisting -- preamble -- PDF}

\mytcbInputListing{input_example_preamble}

\mytcbInputListing[comment style={raster columns=1, colframe=red!85!black, boxrule=2pt, 
  graphics options={viewport=5cm 24.5cm 8cm 25.5cm,clip}}]{input_example_preamble}

\section{LTXinputExample -- preamble -- inside tcolobox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=red!70!black, colback=red!10!white, coltitle=red!10!white]
  \LTXinputExample[style=estiloExemVerm]{input_example_preamble}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    bicolor,
    lower separated=true,
    breakable,
    colframe=red!70!black, colback=red!10!white, coltitle=red!10!white,
    colbacklower=white,
    %sidebyside,
    overlay={
      \draw[dashed, red!80!black,thick] (segmentation.north)--(segmentation.south);
    },
  ]
\LTXinputExample[style=estiloExemVerm, rframe={}]{input_example_preamble}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `standalone` package loaded, `\tcbinputlisting{listing file=input_example_preamble, sidebyside}` would do part of the job. But it gets more complex if you don't want to fully ignore the preamble of subfile.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ, indeed, `standalone` solves the preamble part of the job, but the idea of the example is have something functional in a file, that an be showed at other file, pretty much that's possible with `showexpl` through `\LTXinputExample`. I got pretty close in section 4, which would be perfect if I could answer Q2 to automatically find the limits of the text as I manually did. At the moment, this is the best solution (with these restrictions) I found out.